# Getting subdomains with co.cc and ZoneEdit

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, zoneedit

I'm really lost and my native language is not English so It's difficult to understand some of the complicated Apache Doc pages.

I've set up a **Apache 2 webserver** on an old Macintosh (Mac OS X 10.4.11, but also on a GNU/Linux box with same config files, but of course not at the same time ;) ).

The **DocumentRoot is /Users/enrique/Sites**, I know it's not the best but it works and I don't have permissions error when I mount the shared folder on other computers in my LAN.

I set up a **free domain** at co.cc let's say it is *mysuperdomain.co.cc*

I've also set up a ZoneEdit DNS account. I made a new zone called "mysuperdomain.co.cc" and then using an app called DNSUpdate with my Zoneedit data to update my dynamic IP (it usually changes twice a month with my ISP). It works fine and I can use ssh, VNC, FTP and of course my apache webserver from anywhere. I tried to VNC the Mac from a computer shop in Germany (I live in Spain) and I was great... and It saved me as I could recover some documents...

I usually ssh my server and edit the config file from there, or I use webmin if I'm in a Windows box and I don't have a SSH client.

**Well, this is the problem:** I had configured a virtualhost by hand first, and then again with webmin (maybe I was missing something) with the address doc.mysuperdomain.co.cc and DocumentRoot /Users/enrique/Sites/data/doc because I want to take it apart from my other folders.

Well, If I type doc.mysuperdomain.co.cc on my browser it takes me to the default Index page.

Why doesn't it take me to the *right* folder?

I don't know what to do. I think buying a "full" domain is now a bit expensive (and that doc folder is for educational purposes). With a, say, .net or .com personal domain will I be able to use subdomains with my free zoneedit account?

If someone can save me I'll be the happiest man on Earth...

**Update:**

I say I'm lost. This is what I have in my httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost mysuperdomain.co.cc:80

<VirtualHost doc.mysuperdomain.co.cc:80>
DocumentRoot /Users/enrique/Sites/doc
ServerName mysuperdomain.co.cc
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not using an external httpd-vhosts.conf, shall I use it?

I had tried putting another Vhost with the main domain (mysuperdomain.co.cc) pointing at the documentroot (Users/enrique/Sites), with no luck.

I think it's something I typed wrong (Apache doc is quite difficult to understand, and some pages are not updated in the spanish version...)... but maybe using a free co.cc domain is the problem. I'll cross my fingers and wait that is a configuration error.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Apache configuration for the doc.mysuperdomain.co.cc using the ServerName directive? ServerName is used to map the host name to the virtual host.

Also, if you are using httpd-vhosts.conf, make sure it is enabled in your primary httpd.conf file.